# Can a verb be used as a linking verb and an auxiliary verb in a compound predicate sentence?

Tags: compound-predicates

For instance, the "are" in "I hope you are well and having a good weekend." is being used as a linking verb in the first predicated and as an auxiliary in the second. Should this become: "I hope you are well and are having a good weekend."

Comment: There is no "are" in the second coordinate. The coordination consists of the adverb "well" + the gerund-participial clause "having a good weekend", both of which are complements of "are". Btw, "be" is always an auxiliary verb even when it's the only verb in the sentence.

Comment: That's one way to look at it. Another is to speak of deletion of repeated elements in the second conjunct. This makes the parallelism clearer and relates the two sentences, with and without the deletion, as equivalent and grammatical, part of a system of rules and constructions. I would say there is no "are" in the second coordinate, but there was one.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/614851/2085).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's no grammatical issue here; you typically don't need to repeat words at the start of different conjuncts, and none of the exceptions to that rule apply here.

Stylistically, however, it may not sound great. It's essentially a case of zeugma ([see Wikipedia, under "Type 2"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeugma_and_syllepsis)); while this can be a clever figure of speech, it also makes sentences harder to understand.

Fortunately, you can easily rephrase it by using "well" as an adverb with essentially the same meaning:

> I hope you are **doing** well and are having a good weekend.